# Why is the runtime of the first code more than the second code in this Palendrome number program

Tags: python, runtime

I was solving a code on leet code and noticed that the time complexity of the first algorithm is more than the second algorithm even though they seem to be pretty similar.

```
class Solution:

    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:

        y=str(x)

        return y==y[::-1]
```

is 64ms meanwhile

```
class Solution:

    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        y=str(x)
        rev = y[::-1]
        return rev==y
```

is just 44 ms. I am pretty new to competitive programming.

Comment: Your two functions are logically identical.  I suggest doing a better job of benchmarking, because the two points of data you have may not be statistically significant.

Comment: Take a look at the generated byte code to see what the differences are. There might be some differences in optimization due to the introduction of the variable.

Comment: Also, note that different speed != different time complexity.

Comment: Can you extend the question to include details of how you're benchmarking, so that the problem is reproducible? It's very likely you've made a mistake in your methodology.

Comment: I am not sure what you guys mean by benchmarking, i tested my code against the test cases and the default compiler gave me the results. The question was about determining a palindrome number.